# Does Shell's "Nitrogen enriched" gas have positive effects?

Tags: energy-efficiency, fossil-fuel, gasoline

Shell gas stations here in Canada claim to be "nitrogen enriched";

---

WHY SHOULD YOU USE SHELL NITROGEN ENRICHED GASOLINE?

> It is the only gasoline that contains the patented and exclusive Shell Nitrogen Enriched Cleaning System
>
> Extensively tested for more than half-million miles in various engines and vehicles
>
> Actively cleans performance-robbing gunk from intake values and fuel injectors
>
> Acts like a protective barrier to shield fuel injectors and intake valves against future gunk build up
>
> Exceeds the stringent requirements of the world’s top automakers –  Audi, BMW, General Motors, Honda, Toyota and Volkswagen – and is certified as a TOP TIER Detergent Gasoline
>
> No other gasoline protects better!

---

I looked around, but I couldn't really find any conclusive tests on wether it actually had a cleaning and performance-enhancing effect.

Does it work as well as claimed?

Comment: I couldn't find any info about the patent that Shell issued in the first place. It's nowhere on the site, and I didn't find anything with keywords "nitrogen", "cleaning", "gasoline" either, so as of now, I doubt it. However, there's a possibility that I didn't use correct keyword either.

Comment: On shell's site here: http://www.shell.ca/en/products-services/shell-for-drivers/fuels/nitrogen-enriched-gasolines.html it says explicitly that it's patented, and I don't think shell's one to lie; perhaps it's only in Canada?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A good starting point for information about this topic is [The Gasoline Wars](http://cen.acs.org/articles/87/i14/Gasoline-Wars.html) Chemical & Engineering News, vol. 87, pages 20-21.

First, when shell says "nitrogen-enriched", it does not mean that nitrogen itself (such as dinitrogen in air) is added to the gasoline. Instead, it means that an [amine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amine) detergent compound is added to the gasoline.

Secondly, amine detergent compounds have been know for a long time to have cleaning effects.  Various companies use specific amine compounds in their fuels.

There is a US patent [7901470 Gasoline Additives](http://www.google.com/patents/US7901470) that is assigned to Shell and involves compounds of the form:

CH<sub>3</sub>(CH<sub>2</sub>)<sub>n</sub>NH<sub>2</sub> where n is between 9 and 17, such as [dodecylamine](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj2-_qb-7rJAhVX-GMKHbBDBlEQFggqMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov%2Fcompound%2Fdodecylamine&usg=AFQjCNHTFZr1uZoeiWn_-e4nywlf0czNKQ).

This patent includes test results concerning deposits in engines.